# Movie where people's memories can be recorded using chips in their eyes

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this movie in 2014, when I was only 11, so I can't remember it.

It's about a couple in a future where people can record their memories with some chip or something in their eye. I remember a scene where they just stood in bed and watched a memory of themselves having sex rather than actually having sex. And the guy had a big house and there was a car chase. I also remember that the wife leaked the husband's memories on TV or something.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_Days_(film) might fit except that I don't remember a broadcast.

Comment: I was thinking either strange days or something like Demolition Man. I think there might have been a Twilight Zone similar to this too.

Comment: Also [*Brainstorm*](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/Brainstorm) although, again, no broadcast.

Answer (score 48):

You might be looking for [The Entire History of You](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Entire_History_of_You), which is not a movie but an episode of [Black Mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Mirror).
It originally aired in 2011 so you could have definitively watched it in 2014.

(***Note**: I take this all from the plot page on Wikipedia, because like you I have watched this episode a couple of years ago and I don't remember all the details.*)

> It's about a couple in a future where people can record their memories with some chip or something in their eye.

They use a device called a "grain". It records everything they experience and it can be used to "re-do" i.e. re-watch whatever they want selectively. The episode is centered around a couple having some marital trouble.

> I remember a scene where they just stood in bed and watched a memory of themselves having sex rather than actually having sex.

There is a sex scene after the couple reconciles which includes them watching previous sexual encounters.

> And the guy had a big house and there was a car chase.

Not a chase but he does wreck his car while totally drunk.

> I also remember that the wife leaked the husband's memories on TV or something.

The husband eventually "forces" (in the psychological sense) his wife to show the memory of her having sex with another man. She shows it on the TV in their house as far as I recall.

Comment: It may be relevant that 2014 is when Netflix first acquired the series, so for non-UK viewers it would have been "new".

Comment: I find it slightly disconcerting that an 11-year-old was watching this "Black Mirror" episode. Isn't the series 18 +?

Comment: @VaibhavGarg I can't actually find an "age rating" on Netflix. There is a "parental guide" on [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2085059/parentalguide). Every country has it's own rating, of course. But on average the guide gives either 15/16 or 18+ as a rating. So yes, it's intended for "mature" audiences. But here is hardly the right place to discuss "parenting issues".

Comment: @Sebastian_H You are correct, of course. Being a father of a 10-year-old, I was just wondering out loud!

Answer (score 13):

This is almost certainly "The Entire History of You", an episode of the British Channel 4 anthology series "Black Mirror" (which later moved to Netflix).  In the future, an implant called a "grain" records everything you see, say and do.  The memories can be reviewed, and even displayed to others on external devices.

Answer (score 9):

Honorable mention for [Wim Wender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wim_Wenders)'s 1991 film *[Until The End of the World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Until_the_End_of_the_World)*, which features recordings of (some of) the main characters' memories and dreams (made by a viewfinder-like device over their eyes), their increasing absorption with living in those recordings (to the point of detachment and dissociation), and car chases.

Not sure about leaked recordings to TV.

Aside: *Holy Moly!* Was Wenders ever *crazy prescient* about self-absorption and "the disease of images!"

Comment: Another honourable mention to "Death Watch", the movie based on the D.G. Compton novel "The Continuous Katherine Mortenhoe" (a.k.a. "The Unsleeping Eye").

Answer (score 6):

Possibly "The Final Cut" with Robin Williams.

He plays a character who is a, "Cutter".  Where he edits people's recorded memories to display at people's funerals.

He cuts a memory of a wealthy family, which may fit the large house part.  Additionally, he is chased due to his profession, but I can't recall a car chase in-particular.